# What does the following assembly instruction do addsd -8(%rbp), %xmm0?

Tags: x86, x86-64, sse2, assembly, memory-access

I'm trying to figure out what the assembly instruction actually does

```
addsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
```

I know that it's a floating point addition on an x86-64 machine with SSE2. Also, I know that %xmm0 is a register. However, what I'm not sure of is what -8(%rbp) means. The manuals are a bit confusing on that.

Basically, the question is, does -8(%rbp) mean that it's taking a value from a register (maybe the last 8 bytes of rbp) or is it taking a value from memory (floating point value at an offset of -8 from the address contained in rbp).

Comment: Your second guess is correct. It's accessing the value at `-8` bytes offset from address `rbp`.

Comment: Hey Mysticial, can you point to a reference that explains this easily?

Comment: Confusing AT&T syntax strikes again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your second guess is correct. It's accessing the value at `-8` bytes offset from address `rbp`.

Assuming AT&T syntax, this instruction loads an 8-byte `double` from address `rbp - 8` and adds it to the value in the lower half of `xmm0`.

Comment: Can you point to a reference that explains this easily? Most of the assembly language tutorials and references are hopelessly obfuscated (or so I feel. maybe it's just me)

Comment: I'm trying to find one right now. But the relative addressing thing might be a bit on the basic side.